# How can I prevent my code from reverse engineering?

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard

My project.properties is set up correctly, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the proguard config file:

[image]

So I exported the APK file, and decompiled it with an online APK decompiler:

[image]

[image]

But all the code is still unsafe, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

I did the instructions, what am I doing wrong? Could you please help me?

Comment: The answer is one: **You can't prevent reverse engineering**

Comment: Don't release your app?

Comment: Without knowing what your program does: if you have confidential logic, you should keep it on the server.

Comment: Question "what am I doing wrong?" Answer: posting screenshots that nobody can read instead of just the text from the files.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse Engineering is unfortunately something we are going to have to live with. You can make it more difficult for example through obfuscation, but there is now way to prevent it. If parts of your code is confidential or you need to store sensitive data than you can move it to a server and offer that functionality for example through a web service. But aside from that there is not much you can do.